# Compare two matrices with Boolean statement in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Simple questions

v = [1,2,3,4]
w = [1,2,4,4]

v == w

returns

1 1 0 1

It compares entry by entry, why not the whole array and return 0? How to accomplish that?

Also if I see the datatype it's a 1x4 logical, what does it mean; a 1x4 matrix with logical datatypes?

I didn't knew a matrix could contain logical datatypes. How to convert a 1x4 logical matrix to a matrix with numeric datatypes?

So these are my questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Why does** [**`==`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) **compare entry by entry?**

The answer is simply that this is exactly what it is made for.  As given in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html):

> `A == B` returns a logical array with elements set to logical `1` (`true`)
>   where arrays `A` and `B` are equal; otherwise, the element is logical `0`
>   (`false`) ...

To compare the whole array, as given in [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43260601/5698672), [**`isequal`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) can be used. If you want to use `==`, you will also have to use [**`all`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.htmlhttps://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) with it like this: `all(v==w)`.

---

**What does a matrix with logical datatypes mean?**

Logical matrix is a matrix whose elements are either `true` (`1`) or `false` (`0`) . In literature, sometimes it is also referred to as **boolean matrix** or **binary matrix**.

---

**How to convert a logical matrix to a matrix with numeric datatype?**

There are several data types e.g. [**`single`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html), [**`double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), [**`int64`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int64.html), [**`uint64`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html) etc. Use the function designated for the data type that you want to convert into. Read more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can do element by element or just use the function

```
isequal(v,w)
```